# Simple Javascript drop down menu box

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I know this question has been asked a few times, but I'm searching for a more simple approach. Most of the questions are for a full Javascript drop down menu, but I'm just after one small box. Looked everywhere, and this has not been answered.

I am learning Javascript from a text book I purchased, so I'd prefer it if someone helped me, or if you prefer to just give straight up answers, just a bit of commenting would be appreciated so I know whats going on. I'd prefer to use plain Javascript instead of jQuery since I am learning from a Javascript only text book.

I am creating a mini social network kind of page. And at the top right, I have the persons username, with an arrow next to it. I am trying to make a dropdown box, when that arrow is clicked, and inside that dropdown box will be a 'Sign Out' button, and 'Settings' button. I honestly have no idea where to start since this is something extra I am attempting.

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel when Bootstrap gives you a nice and simple dropdown menu.  You can customize and pick what you want from Bootstrap  so you don't have useless css and javascript.  (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#dropdowns)

Comment: Looks like this question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362670/simple-javascript-dropdown-menu

Comment: @icanc - As I stated, I am learning Javascript, so I need to know how to do things like this is plain Javascript with no librarys.

Comment: @AlexMarchant - That is a similar question, yes, although it does not answer the question directly at all. The links given are not answering my question at all, and the example code given does not work properly at all.

Comment: @Icanc why load a library with support for Button groups
Button dropdowns
Navigational tabs, pills, and lists
Navbar
Labels
Badges
Page headers and hero unit
Thumbnails
Alerts
Progress bars
Modals
Dropdowns
Tooltips
Popovers
Accordion
Carousel
Typeahead when all the OP wants is a display=none/block div on mouseover?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find the sample code below. We can do it many ways. This is simple one for JavaScript beginners.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function showDiv(){
    if(document.getElementById('showDiv').style.display == 'none'){
        document.getElementById('showDiv').style.display = 'block';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('showDiv').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:auto;; margin:0 auto;">
    <div style="position:relative; width:130px; padding:10px; float:left; border:1px solid blue;">
        <div style="float:left;">Welcome Friend!</div>
        <div style="float:left; margin-left:15px;" onclick="showDiv();">></div>  

    </div>
    <div id="showDiv" style="display:none; float:right; width:150px; height:50px; position:absolute; margin-top:40px; border:1px solid red;">
        <div style="float:right;"><input type="submit" value="Settings" /></div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <div style="float:right;"><input type="submit" value="Sign Out" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: make the > a link, then you get the hand for free, or give it a pointer cursor. Also all CSS could be in a stylesheet and all JS in the head, including the onclick - let's teach Jade good practises :)

Comment: @Vijayakumar Chandrasek - That code is perfect and performs exactly what I need :) Very simple and easy to read. I'll give it a shot and start building off it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Here is a cleaner version, but it needs more http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/dGRmQ/ - close menu on escape or onclick outside the menu and there are some CSS issues - jade, view-source of http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/dGRmQ/show

Comment: @JadeMulholland: I just handcoded here but as per mplungjan comments it should be separate only. :)